# Delete line if next line is the same

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

What sed/awk command can I use? Just `sort -u` will remove all instances

Input:

```
abc
abc
def
abc
abc
def
```

Expected output:

```
abc
def
abc
def
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's what the `uniq` standard command is for.

```
uniq your-file
```

Note that some `uniq` implementations like GNU `uniq` will give you the first of a sequence of lines that *sort the same* (where `strcoll()` returns 0) as opposed to *are byte-to-byte identical* (where `memcmp()` or `strcmp()` returns 0). To force a byte to byte comparison regardless of the `uniq` implementation, you can force the locale to `C` with:

```
LC_ALL=C uniq your-file
```

Answer (score 7):

Vim can achieve this nicely:

```
:g/\v^(.*\n)\1/d
```

Or if you'd rather use vim as a command line tool, you could do this as

```
vim file -c "g/\v^(.*\n)\1/d" -c "wq"
```

This way you don't have to wrestle with exiting vim later ;)

Explanation:

```
:g/
```

On all lines that match this regex...

```
\v^(.*\n)\1
```

Any line followed by itself...

```
/d
```

run the **d**elete command (delete the current line). The `-c "wq"` is to save the changes and exit.

Comment: Note that with vim 8.1.2112 at least, it doesn't work for duplicated lines that are the last two lines of the file. Also, it only removes one duplicate from sequences of 3 duplicate lines.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas except that we currently lack specification for desired behavior in the 3-line case—I could see desired behavior both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` equivalent:

```
awk 'p!=$0; {p=$0}' file
```

`p!=$0;` print line if it is not identical to previous one, `;` is necessary here.
`{p=$0}` set `p` to current line.

An obvious bug is missing the first line if it's empty. A simple fix is:

```
awk 'NR==1 || p!=$0; {p=$0}' file
```